# Why is this else statement printing every time?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a simple text game. For some reason when I input the correct text the else text will always be output, along with the correct output text. The else text should only be displayed if incorrect text is input. What am I doing wrong?

```
//take commands
if (input == "text 1" && currentroom == "area_1")
    $("<p>reply 1.</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
else if (input == "text 1" && "currentroom" != "area_1")
    $("<p>reply 2.</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);


//got to room 
if (input == "go to area 2" && "currentroom" == "area_1") {
    currentroom = "area_outside";
    $("<p>You are now  in area 2.</p>");
} else if (input == "go to area 2" && "currentroom" != "area_1")
    $("<p>You cant go that way.</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);

if (input == "go to area 1" && "currentroom" == "area_2") {
    currentroom = "area_outside";
    $("<p>You are back in area 1.</p>")
} else { //invaild commands/dont understand.
    $("<p>"+input+" is not vaild. type help for vaild commands.</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
}
```

Comment: You should to separate any DOM manipulations from your game engine. Another case you'll receive something unsupportable.

Comment: "currentroom" == "area_2". Did you checked this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `else` at the end is **only** connected to this `if`:

```
if (input == "go to area 1" && "currentroom" == "area_2")
```

So if `input == "go to area 1"` is false or `"currentroom" == "area_2"` is false (which it always will be), your `else` code will be run.

You probably meant that to be

```
if (input == "go to area 1" && currentroom == "area_2")
// No quotes ------------------^----------^
```

there and in a couple of other places, and you *may* or may not want to use `else if` in a couple of places you've used `if`.

So perhaps:

```
if (input == "text 1" && currentroom == "area_1") {
    $("<p>reply 1.</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
}
else if (input == "text 1" && currentroom != "area_1") {
    $("<p>reply 2.</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
}
else if (input == "go to area 2" && currentroom == "area_1") {
    currentroom = "area_outside";
    $("<p>You are now  in area 2.</p>")
}
else if (input == "go to area 2" && currentroom != "area_1") {
    $("<p>You cant go that way.</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
}
else if (input == "go to area 1" && currentroom == "area_2") {
    currentroom = "area_outside";
    $("<p>You are back in area 1.</p>")
}
else {
    //invaild commands/dont understand.
    $("<p>" + input + " is not vaild. type help for vaild commands.</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
}
```

...although you may be able to refactor that a bit.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have `else if` instead of `if`

```
//take commands
if (input == "text 1" && currentroom == "area_1") {
    $("<p>reply 1.</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
}
else if (input == "text 1" && "currentroom" != "area_1") {
    $("<p>reply 2.</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
}

//got to room 
else if (input == "go to area 2" && "currentroom" == "area_1") {
    currentroom = "area_outside";
    $("<p>You are now  in area 2.</p>")
}
else if (input == "go to area 2" && "currentroom" != "area_1") {
    $("<p>You cant go that way.</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
}
else if (input == "go to area 1" && "currentroom" == "area_2") {
    currentroom = "area_outside";
    $("<p>You are back in area 1.</p>")
}

//invaild commands/dont understand.
else {
    $("<p>"+input+" is not vaild. type help for vaild commands.</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
}
```

Comment: That's *one* problem, yes.

Answer (score 0):

```
"currentroom" == "area_2"
```

It's always a false. If currentroom is a variable remove the quotes from it.

Answer (score 0):

Just demonstrate what I meant by

> You should to separate any DOM manipulations from your game engine.
>   Another case you'll receive something unsupportable.

Simple step is to extract reply method:

```
var game = {
  reply: function(msg) {
    $("<p>"+msg+"</p>")
      .hide()
      .insertBefore("#placeholder")
      .fadeIn(1000);
  }
};
```

And now we can to write logic simple:

```
switch(input) {
  case 'text 1':
    game.reply(currentroom == 'area_1' ? "reply 1." : "reply 2.");
  break;
  case 'go to area 2':
    switch(currentroom) {
      case 'area_1':
        currentroom = 'area_outside';
        game.reply("You are now in area 2.");
      break;
      default:
        game.reply("You cant go that way.");
    }
  break;
  default:
    game.reply('Wrong input');
}
```

Then we can to incapsulate movings and etc.:

```
game.moveTo = function(room) {
  // game normally should to know available rooms list
  // if (!this.rooms[room]) return this.reply('Unknown room ' + room);
  if (room === this.currentRoom) return this.reply('You are already here!');
  this.currentRoom = room;
  this.reply('You now in '+room);
}
```

Comment: Completely restructuring the OP's code may be a good idea, but **this completely ignores the question they actually asked** about why their `else` case always executes.

Comment: @nnnnnn, Just don't upvote this. It's not an answer, just bit of help. There are nice and correct answers here already.